# Android TV Leanback fragment scrolling doesn't work fine in mobile

Tags: android, scroll, leanback

I have an app already developed for Android TV boxes. I want it to be compatible with mobile as well, therefore I tried to run the app on my phone(Google Pixel 3, not sure if the model is the problem).
All worked good enough except scrolling.
When I try to scroll, it snaps back to the beginning.

I don't think any code is needed for you to solve this issue.
The fragment which I used is BrowseSupportFragment in Leanback.

Look forward to hearing a good answer from anyone.
Best!

Comment: have you solved the issue?